# How to check Google Service Account expiration time

Tags: c#, google-api, service-accounts

I'm making an app with Xamarin.forms that uploads images to a specific folder of a specific google drive. To do this I'm using a service account. Here's the code to authorize the service account:

```
    private async Task<bool> AuthenticateServiceAccountAsync()
    {
        var serviceAccount = await GetFirstResourceStringWithName(_ServiceAccountKey);
        if(serviceAccount == null)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayExceptionAlert(new Exception("Service account key not found. Unable to authenticate."));
            return false;
        }

        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

        try
        {
            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(serviceAccount)
                     .CreateScoped(scopes);

            _DriveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "MyAppName"
            });

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayExceptionAlert(
                e,
                "No se pudo inicializar la cuenta de servicio.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Works flawlessly, but I don't know how to check for expiration, there are no token visible both in `GoogleCredential` or in `DriveService` types.

Well, that's not entirely true, one can get a token with `GoogleCredential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()`, but thats only the token string with no info about expiration time as far as I can tell. Seems useless in these circumstances.

Should I just make a `DateTime` field and check if an hour has passed since the service account got authenticated?

Comment: You want to know the remaining time of the access token retrieved by Service Account. If my understanding is correct, how about using oauth2.tokeninfo method? You can test it at [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo). When you put the access token to ``access_token`` and click "Execute", you can see the remaining time at ``expires_in``. If the expiration time is over, ``Invalid Value`` is returned. I posted it as a comment because I'm not sure whether this is the method what you want. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Tokeninfo is a method? I only see a type called `Tokeninfo`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed tokeninfo as a method of oauth2. If above proposal was not useful for your situation, I have to apologize. How about this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, oauth2 is a namespace and Tokeninfo a type. You are describing it as if oauth2 were an object and Tokeninfo a method one could call like `oauth2.Tokeninfo()`. But that's not the case, I fail to see how I could do that, I don't see that method.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. And also I apologize for my poor skill and experiences.

Comment: there is no way to read token expiration for GoogleCredential, as google documents says you will know is token not valid when your request statusCode = 401 in this case you must re-create new token .